# 64-bit MSI executes as a 32-bit one

Tags: windows-installer

I've created an MSI package (in Orca). The Platform field in the summary information says "x64;1033". The machine is a 64 bit one. The schema version, in case it matters, is 400.

When I run it with with MSIExec like this:

> msiexec /qn /li a.txt /i b.msi

**I can see that it executes in a 32 bit process.** Not the intended result.

To check, I've placed a value under HKLM\SOFTWARE - `Bits`, REG_SZ, value "64", and a similar one under HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node, but with value "32", and I dump that value in a custom JScript action early in the install sequence. I get "32".

The copy of `msiexec` that I run is under c:\Windows\System32, it's a 64 bit executable, and it's not supposed to matter anyway, the installer is not running in the msiexec process AFAIK.

The `Platform` in the summary info is not completely ignored - if I specify "Intel64", which stands for Itanium, I get an "Unsupported architecture" error. Tried "AMD64" - it's only option in Orca if you provide Schema>=500 - same result, 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom actions have their own bitness each**. For DLL-type actions, it's derived from the target architecture of the DLL. For script-type actions, where bitness can't be inferred, the `Type` field value must be ORred with 0x1000 (`msidbCustomActionType64BitScript`, decimal 4096) for a 64-bit execution context.

A script action without that bit set will be executed in a 32-bit environment even in an otherwise 64-bit targeting MSI. That was my case.

The issue at hand, *as observed*, was an artifact of the the way the bitness check was implemented. That said, in case of this particular MSI there was a custom action script that was *not* bitness agnostic, so the root cause of this issue mattered to the project.

One presumes the same applies on ARM/ARM64; I could not test.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/64-bit-custom-actions